# Free vpn for Linux

Tags: open-source, ubuntu, vpn

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and I need a vpn client which runs on Linux. The program should be free or open source.

Comment: For clarification: Do you want to install VPN software on your Linux machine, to be used remotely e.g. with your laptop, tablet or smartphone ("VPN Server") – or do you want to use some VPN your Linux machine should connect to ("VPN Client")? Further note we recommend *software* here, not [howtos](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/882/185) or [manuals/tutorials](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1258/185) ;)

Comment: @Izzy: am looking for a simple and free software like psiphon on Linux.

Comment: We will need much more information to give good recommendations here – asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked. You should always list your requirements explicitly. Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details. Some people (myself included) might never have heard of psiphon – if they would know the features you need, they could still know a software matching them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Windscribe encrypts your browsing activity, blocks ads, and unblocks
>   entertainment content.

Note: It isn't open source but free.

Free version comes with:

- Devices: Unlimited
- Locations: 11
- Bandwidth: 10GB+/Month
- OpenVPN Configs: No
- Firewall: Yes
- Adblock: Yes
- P2P: Yes

[Windscribe homepage](https://windscribe.com/)

[Installation and usage information for Ubuntu 16.04](https://windscribe.com/guides/linux)

Comment: Does it have traffic limitation?

Comment: Yes it's shown in my answer. 10GB+/Month